# Vector stationarity test

Tags: time-series, stationarity

I have a column vector $A$ with $n$ rows that changes over time. Instead of thinking about this vector as a point in higher dimensional space, I like to think about it as a curve on a plane where the horizontal axis is the elements' positions and the vertical axis their values. I created a graph in python that shows how this curve changes over time.

[image: Curve over time]

I don't know much statistics (and even less time-series) but at a high level I was wondering if there is a test I could use to determine if this curve retains its shape over time (independent of the curve's location in space). The only thing I could think of doing is test for the stationarity of the differences of all the elements with respect to one of them, but this wouldn't describe the entire curve at once.

It is very possible I'm thinking about this in an odd way and there is a simpler way to think about it so any comments or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

###### Clarification:

When talking about shape, I mean for any scalar $c > 0$, $cA$ has the same shape as $A$.

Also, I suspect the elements of $A$ are Wiener processes but are also somehow correlated with the other elements (which is why this vector seems to retain its basic "shape").

Comment: Please tell us what you mean by a curve's "shape:" there are many different reasonable candidates for what this might mean.

Comment: @whuber By shape I mean each elements value relative to the others

Comment: In other words, if (as vectors) one curve had the sequence of values $(y_1, y_2, \ldots, y_n)$ and another had the sequence $(ay_1, ay_2, \ldots, ay_n)$ for some constant $a\ne 0,$ would they have the same shape, and *vice versa*?  If that's so, then to develop a test we also need to know your statistical assumptions: how might one curve vary randomly?

Comment: @whuber I'd say the example you gave works for $a > 0$. I'm not exactly sure how the curve varies but I suspect each element on its own is similar to a Wiener process (I don't know the formal definition), however, there is definitely some correlation between all the elements because visually the curve appears to maintain the same basic shape. As a side question, should I be adding these details to the original question?

Comment: Yes, please: it's always better to put everything in the body of the question itself.  It's OK to restrict to $a\gt 0;$ I'm only trying to obtain an accurate, useful, definition of what you mean by "same shape," whatever that might be. Might I point out, though, that the vector representation is now *very* useful? Any given shape of your curve corresponds to a point on a hypersphere and any curve that changes over time is just a path on this hypersphere. I'm not sure you need a formal *test.* Maybe you just need to visualize that curve?

Comment: @whuber I have made some clarifications in the question. Could you elaborate on the hypersphere idea? Is this different than plotting the vector in $n$-dimensional space (which I was trying to avoid because I don't know how to visualize anything higher than 3D)?

Comment: Your question doesn't require visualization: "retain its shape over time" can be interpreted as "is consistent with being a single point on the hypersphere that varies completely at random." That suggests two avenues of inquiry: first, to *measure* the spread of the path on the hypersphere (which tells us *how much* variation in shape is occurring) and second to assess the *randomness* of that path. The latter would be greatly aided by any information you might have about how or why your curves are varying: is it truly a Wiener process, or perhaps something else?

Comment: @whuber How would you go about measuring the spread of the path on the hypersphere? Also, I was hoping that analyzing the shape of the curve over time could tell me something about the individual elements and not the other way around.

Comment: A natural metric to use would be the geodesic distance on the sphere, but whether that's appropriate will depend on your probability model.  For instance, if these curves truly are realizations of a Wiener process, then you might want to weight the components by the reciprocal of the elapsed time.  I don't understand your second remark.

Comment: @whuber After a quick google search I'm thinking I'll use $d=acos(A_{t} \cdot A_{t-1}) $for distance and see what that does. My last comment was in response to your last comment:  "The latter would be greatly aided by any information you might have about how or why your curves are varying" -- I took "curves" to mean the curves of the individual elements.

Comment: @whuber Could you explain why you suggested using geodesic distance on a sphere rather than Minkowski distance?

Comment: Geodesic distance is the distance inherited from the Euclidean metric.  It's unclear why one might want to use any Minkowski distance in this problem.

Comment: @whuber I'm just trying to understand why distance on a sphere and not what I would naively call "straight line distance"

Comment: The geodesic distance *is* the straight line distance on the sphere.  It's identical to how you measure your own travel on the surface of the earth.  It's sometimes called the "cosine distance" in machine learning.

Comment: @whuber Sorry I guess what I meant was why on a sphere? When I said "straight line distance" I meant the higher dimensional equivalent of chord length on a circle. I am imagining geodesic distance is the higher dimensional equivalent of the arc length on a circle.

Comment: Technically, when you consider two nonzero points in $\mathbb{R}^n$ to be equivalent when they are in a constant positive ratio, you are describing the space of rays in $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus \{0\}.$ This is in a natural one-to-one correspondence with any sphere centered at the origin.